# multiple (independent) reduce functions after map

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My map function emits two different kinds of key value pairs for the same data. Naturally I would need 2 independent reduce functions to handle this. Is it possible?

Like, can I have multiple output.collect() statements at the end of map with an additional parameter specifying the reducer?
I tried looking it up but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [MultipleOutputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) class. It has nice and self-explanatory documentation.